# Check for a specific url and render jinja2 / html

Tags: html, django, jinja2

How can check for a specific URL in jinja2 within html files and then render different html files based on what URL I am currently at?

For eg.

```
# if {{ request.path == /siteID/ }}
  {% include "file1.html" %}

# if {{ request.path == /siteID/abcde/ }}
  {% include "file2.html" %}
```

Current logic I have which I feel is not very good:

```
<!-- ..... bunch of html lines .... -->
{% if request.path|length > 8 and request.path.startswith('/siteID/') and request.path[8:].strip('/').split('/')|length == 1 %}
  {% include "file2.html" %}
{% else %}
  {% include "file1.html" %}
{% endif %}
<!-- ..... bunch of html lines .... -->
```

Also how do I scale this if I want to do something in the future like:

```
# if {{ request.path == /siteID/abcde/uvwxyz }}
  {% include "file3.html" %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to scale this later, don't do this in the template. Put the logic into a view function, then pass a variable to the render function that stores the name of the template you want to include. E.g.:

```
def the_view(request):
    if request.path == '/siteID/abcde/':
        template = 'file1.html'
    elif request.path == '/siteID/fgh/':
        template = 'file2.html'
    else:
        template = 'file_default.html'
        
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'template_to_include': template})
```

Then in your `base.html` template put this dynamic import line somewhere:

```
{% include template_to_include %}
```